# Returning all characters before the first underscore

Tags: python, regex, string

Using `re` in Python, I would like to return all of the characters in a string that precede the first appearance of an underscore. In addition, I would like the string that is being returned to be in all uppercase and **without** any non-alpanumeric characters.

For example:

```
AG.av08_binloop_v6 = AGAV08
TL.av1_binloopv2   = TLAV1
```

I am pretty sure I know how to return a string in all uppercase using `string.upper()` but I'm sure there are several ways to remove the `.` efficiently. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am still learning regular expressions slowly but surely. Each tip gets added to my notes for future use.

To further clarify, my above examples aren't the actual strings. The actual string would look like:

```
AG.av08_binloop_v6
```

With my desired output looking like:

```
AGAV08
```

And the next example would be the same. String:

```
TL.av1_binloopv2
```

Desired output:

```
TLAV1
```

Again, thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
re.sub("[^A-Z\d]", "", re.search("^[^_]*", str).group(0).upper())
```

Comment: +1 "on spec", looks right but I'm not a regex guru. Edit: I'd replace `re.search` with `re.match` and drop the initial `^` in the pattern (`match` always starts at the start of the string and is optimized for this).

Comment: While I like the simplicity of the other answers, I also wanted whatever solution I went with to be useful for further regular expression exploration. This one fits the bill. Thanks Gumbo!

Comment: Just for future knowledge, how would this be done with ``re.compile``? I like the one-liner nature of this, but it would be good to know for future knowledge.

Comment: @durandal: `a = re.compile(r'^A-Z\d')`, `b = re.compile(r'[^_]*')` and `re.sub(a, "", re.search(b, s).group(0).upper())` (substitute descriptive names for a and b). The raw strings (`r"..."`) are not needed here, but I prefer to always use them for regex patterns.

Comment: Actually creating regular expression objects using `re.compile` makes it clearer that what you wrote, delnan (you just substitued the string expression with the compiled one). You can actually call `a.sub( "", b.search( s ).group(0).upper() )` instead.

Answer (score 24):

Even without `re`:

```
text.split('_', 1)[0].replace('.', '').upper()
```

Comment: personally I find this more readable and understandable at first glance and would therefore prefer to read this in my codebase than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Since everyone is giving their favorite implementation, here's mine that doesn't use `re`:

```
>>> for s in ('AG.av08_binloop_v6', 'TL.av1_binloopv2'):
...     print ''.join(c for c in s.split('_',1)[0] if c.isalnum()).upper()
...
AGAV08
TLAV1
```

I put `.upper()` on the outside of the generator so it is only called once.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use `re` for this. Simple string operations would be enough based on your requirements:

```
tests = """
AG.av08_binloop_v6 = AGAV08
TL.av1_binloopv2   = TLAV1
"""

for t in tests.splitlines(): 
     print t[:t.find('_')].replace('.', '').upper()

# Returns:
# AGAV08
# TLAV1
```

Or if you absolutely must use `re`:

```
import re 

pat = r'([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)_.*'
pat_re = re.compile(pat)

for t in tests.splitlines():
    print re.sub(r'\.', '', pat_re.findall(t)[0]).upper()

# Returns:
# AGAV08
# TLAV1
```

Comment: While I agree that regexes don't cure cancer and are generally overused, they *are* a viable choice for tasks like this one.

Comment: Viable, yes. But overcomplicated for such a simple task.

Comment: Gumbo's solution is a rather readable oneliner. If one knows regex basics, it's perfectly clear what it does. It's not like that's a 6k character monster.

Answer (score 2):

He, just for fun, another option to get text before the first underscore is:

```
before_underscore, sep, after_underscore = str.partition('_')
```

So all in one line could be:

```
re.sub("[^A-Z\d]", "", str.partition('_')[0].upper())
```

Answer (score 1):

import re

re.sub("[^A-Z\d]", "", yourstr.split('_',1)[0].upper())